# problem with updating table after editing

Tags: html, css, laravel

after editing a table and pressing the update button I see a blank page and it shows nothing, could you help me please. Below I show you my code.
 I also have another problem, when editing it shows me the empty fields and not what I put before.

public function edit($id)

```
{

    $car = Car::whereid($id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('edit', compact ('car'));

    }
```

public function update(Request $request, $id)

```
{

    $car = Car::whereid($id)->firstOrFail();

    $car->fill($request->all());

    $car->save();

    Session::flash('message','Auto editado');

    return redirect::to('cars/car');

}
```

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Aplicacion de autos</title>
```

```
@section('title', 'Contact')

@section('content')

<div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <div class="well well bs-component">

            <form action= "{{ route('cars.update', ['car' => $car->id]) }}" method="PUT">

               @csrf

               <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Patente:</label>

                        <input type="text" name="patente" size="6" maxlength="6" class="form-control" required>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Marca:</label>

                        <input type="text" name="marca" class="form-control" required>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Modelo:</label>

                        <input type="text" name="modelo" class="form-control" required>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Color:</label>

                        <input type="text" name="color" class="form-control" required>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <label for="">Fecha_ingreso:</label>

                        <input type="date" name="fecha_ingreso" class="form-control" required>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <button type="submit" class="btm btm-success w-50 float-right">Actualizar</button>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First part - empty table on update - you need to redirect back to your index method.  It looks like you are possibly redirecting back to an edit or show method again (it looks to be a single car route rather than the carS route I would expect from an index method producing a collection of cars).

```
return redirect::to('cars/car');
```

I don't know what your route is, but make sure this line above, inside your `update()` function, is returning to your index view, or `Redirect::back()`.

For your second question on empty fields on the form, the easiest way to resolve this is through form-model binding.  Check out [Laravel Collective's package](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) for a really nice solution.

Comment: Viewing the php artisan route: list the address of update is cars / {car} but the blank page still appears. Do you know what I could do?

Comment: the code that I have is   public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        

        $car = Car::firstOrFail($id);
        $car->patente = $request('patente');
        $car->marca = $request('marca');
        $car->modeo = $request('modelo');
        $car->color = $request('color');
        $car->fecha_ingreso = $request('fecha_ingreso');
        $car->save();
        return redirect('/cars');

    }

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i was saying.  For the incoming update, that is the correct route.  But when you have completed the update in the controller, you are redirecting back to this same page.  Try Redirect::back() .   Well - you were anyway - redirect back to 'cars' should work.  IE `redirect('cars');`  If that is your index route.